# Set default "To Date" based on user-entered "From Date"

Tags: jquery, datepicker

i'm working with PHP and MySQL. in one of my form there are options for leave:

1. maternity
2. Paternity

when a user selects the *from* date, then i want that the to date field should be filled with from date + 90days.

how can i achieve this.i'm using the Datepicker from jQuery UI.

Here is the form:

```html
<select tabindex="1" name="leavetype" id="leavetype" style="width:160px;">
               <option value="">Select</option>
               <option value="Maternity">Maternity</option>
               <option value="Paternity">Paternity</option>
               <option value="Self-marriage">Self-marriage</option>
</select>

<span style="width:50px; display:inline-block">From</span>
<input type="text"  tabindex="1" id="txtForm" name="txtForm" size="12"  />
<span style="width:50px; display:inline-block">To</span>
<input type="text"  tabindex="1" id="txtTo" name="txtTo" size="12"  />
```

i have tried the ajax but somehow its not woking.
Here is jquery-Ajax:

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#txtForm').change(function(){
        var from = $(this).val();
        var type = $('#leavetype').val();
        if(type == 'Maternity'){
             var to = $('#txtTo').datepicker("from", "+3");
                alert(to);
            }else if(type == 'Paternity'){

        });
});
```

Here is the jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/uh7bg0b9/7/

Comment: Please provide a JSfiddle with working datepicker etc. then I'll look into this. You have a typo in `$('#txtForm')` it should probably read `$('#txtFrom')`. N.B. This has nothing to do with ajax.

Comment: @wedi: there is no typo cause i have taken the id as txtForm so #txtForm is right.

Comment: @wedi: here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/uh7bg0b9/7/

Answer (score 0):

I've always used Moment.js for operating with dates

http://momentjs.com/

In this case you can create a new date using your variable 'to'by parsing it
http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/

And once you get a hold of a proper 'moment' date, you can add 30 days:
http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/

Then you can 'unparse' the date to whatever datepicker format you are using and set it to the field you want to fill:
http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree with Jorge on using Moment JS. But a solution in javascript would be something like,

```
var oldDate = new Date($('#txtForm').val());
var newDate = new Date();
newDate.setDate(oldDate.getDate()+90);
console.log(newDate);
```